# *Hot Alter* MySQL Engine Using Master/Slave Method

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL database that is about 19 GB and has about 30 tables inside. The largest table is about 16 GB and has 3,800,000 rows. This MySQL instance is running on a 128 GB SSD drive.

The MySQL version is 5.5. All the 30 tables are in the format of MyISAM. I'm considering alter them into InnoDB altogether. On the other hand, I don't want to suffer from any database down time.

I've heard about this great PHP script by engineers from Facebook. It's called [**Online Schema Change**](https://www.facebook.com/notes/mysql-at-facebook/online-schema-change-for-mysql/430801045932). It uses the master/slave method to realize the desired **hot alter** effect.

Right now I'm seriously considering set up the Master/Slave structure in my (only) SSD drive and run the Facebook script to do the **hot alter engine** task.

However, in its documentation it almost only talks about the most typical scenario, which is adding columns in a InnoDB table. While in my case, my scenario is quite different, which is changing 30 tables' engine from MyISAM into InnoDB.

My question is, is this Facebook approach applicable in my situation? If not, is there any alternative? Thanks.

Comment: if you only have a single DB server, you're open to having unexpected down time anyway.

Comment: @Spudley Thanks! Could you elaborate what is responsible for such unexpected down time?

Comment: with a single server, you're susceptible to any kind of hardware failure on that server. Therefore if you're on a single server, you don't have guaranteed up-time. I know this is off-topic, but if you're down-time due to software maintenance is that big an issue for you, then you should also be equally worried about it from a hardware maintenance perspective.

Comment: @Spudley brings up a good point - if you want a truly high availability system, you want something that is fault tolerant.